# Does Twitter4J search API support Twitter Premium or Enterprise API search end points

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-search

The main purpose of my application is to fetch tweets from twitter and i am using Twitter4J to do this. I have got standard twitter API.

My question is that, would the same implementation using twitter4j work if i subscribe for Premium or Enterprise twitter APis to fetch tweets.

Answer (score -1):

Currently, no - Twitter4J can’t use the Premium/Enterprise APIs.

[Here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries) you find a list of libraries with info whether they support the Premium and Enterprise APIs.